# c# asp net updatepanel cause page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a simple gridview with image button to update value of one of gridview column, by problem is whenever I click the image button it refresh the wholw page and I want the gridview only to be refreshed with updated value, I tried using UpdatePanel but it also refresh the whole page,
any help will be apprechiated.

aspx code:

```
<form id="form1"  runat="server" >
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  CssClass="datatable"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" PageSize="5">
                    <Columns >
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="req_id" HeaderText="request ID" SortExpression="req_id" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="req subject" HeaderText="request subject" SortExpression="req_subject" /> 
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="Button_update" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("req_id") %>' CssClass="yourCssClassIsNeedIt" ImageUrl="Images/under.png" OnClick="btn_under" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
 </form>
```

aspx.cs code:

```
protected void Button_update(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source= DESKTOP-U9437PU; initial Catalog = Mydb; Integrated Security =True;"))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();

       string sql = "update requests_table set stat_id = '2' where req_id ='" 5 "'";
       SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon);
       cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
       cmd1.Dispose();
       sqlCon.Close();
    }
    GridView1.DataBind(); 

}
```

Comment: Did you try to add  `UpdateMode="Conditional"` to your UpdatePanel with  `UpdatePanel1.Update();`?

Comment: where I should add UpdatePanel1.Update();  ?

Comment: I have added  an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59731500/5519709), please check

Comment: I tried the code but still refresh the whole page when I click the image button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [UpdateMode Conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode?view=netframework-4.8):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
     <Triggers>        
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button_update" EventName="Click" />    
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  CssClass="datatable"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" PageSize="5">
            <Columns >
                <asp:BoundField DataField="req_id" HeaderText="request ID" SortExpression="req_id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="req subject" HeaderText="request subject" SortExpression="req_subject" /> 
                <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="Button_update" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("req_id") %>' CssClass="yourCssClassIsNeedIt" ImageUrl="Images/under.png" OnClick="btn_under" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Then you should work call `UpdatePanel1.Update();` as following:

```
protected void Button_update(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source= DESKTOP-U9437PU; initial Catalog = Mydb; Integrated Security =True;"))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();

       string sql = "update requests_table set stat_id = '2' where req_id ='" 5 "'";
       SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon);
       cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
       cmd1.Dispose();
       sqlCon.Close();
    }
    GridView1.DataBind(); 
    UpdatePanel1.Update();

}
```

Comment: I tried the code but still refresh the whole page when I click the image button

Comment: thanks for the replay, I tried the code and I got this error control with the identifier 'Button_update' in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1' could not be found.

Comment: finally I solved the issue thank you for your help the solution was to delete UpdatePanel and create it again thats wierd :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Button_update" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("req_id") %>' CssClass="yourCssClassIsNeedIt" ImageUrl="Images/under.png" OnClick="btn_under" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="javascript:void(0);"  />
```

And this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
```

Comment: I tried the code but still refresh the whole page when I click the button